# Integration of an exponential sinusoidal function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I've been trying to integrate the following function:

$$\int_0^{23}\sin\left({{x\over1.1}-1.472 \over 1.045^{{x\over1.1}-1.472}}\right)\mathrm dx$$

However, I am not sure how to proceed with this. I've never worked with a function of the form $$\sin\left({x\over a^x}\right)$$ before. I tried substituting $$u=\frac{x}{1.1}-1.472,$$ but could not get very far with this method. Further, how would I calculate the same integral but with the sin squared, i.e.

$$\int_0^{23}\sin^2\left({{x\over1.1}-1.472 \over 1.045^{{x\over1.1}-1.472}}\right)\mathrm dx.$$

Thanks!

Comment: @Quanto $$\qquad{{{{}}}}$$

Comment: @Allawonder do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Nothing except for numerical methods. Hence my sending for *Quanto* above. I thought he would notice something. Apparently this integral is not elementary, then.

Comment: @Quanto any thoughts? Appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: I would be shocked if there were any closed form